# Issues With Filtering and Re-Displaying Data ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm trying to filter through the RandomUser api to display either males or females. My current issue is that I can't display the filtered data like I did the original data.

Here's my current code:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const [gender, setGender] = useState('');
  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=500`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(setData);
  }, [])
  


  const FilterData = () => {
    if(gender) {
      var searchedResult
      searchedResult = data.results.filter(
        (e) => e.gender === gender
      );
      console.log(searchedResult)
      console.log(gender)
      setData([searchedResult])
    }
  }


  if(data.results){


    return (
      <div>

        <div>
          <select name="Gender" onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
          </select>
          <button onChange={FilterData()}></button>
        </div>

        <ul>
        {data.results.map(results => (

          <li key={results}>
            <p>{results.name.first} {results.name.last}</p>
            <img src={results.picture.medium}></img>
          </li>
        ))}
        </ul>

      </div>
    )
  }
else{
  return(
    <div>loading...</div>
  )
}
}
```

I think my issue applies to how I originally setup my html with my if/else statement leading to the html constantly showing 'loading...' if I don't have data.results but I'm not too sure on how I'd apply that to my new filtered array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this is by setting your fetched data in state.

Then create another state called something like `filteredData` as to not mutate your fetched data. Once you filter the data, you want a way to go back to the original data to filter it differently.

On selection of a gender, filter through your fetched data and set `filteredData` as an array of people objects with your selected gender.

If `filteredData` exists (which gets set by a `useEffect` when `gender` is changed), map over that to display your data. If there is no `gender` selected (and therefore, no `filteredData`, map over `data.results` array.

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apqhbe6k/)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you initially call setData you're passing the full response, but when you call it in FilterData you are passing in a single element array. And then it doesn't re-render because you are testing for `data.results` which no longer exists.

Try this...

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [gender, setGender] = useState('');


useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setData(data.results)
        });
}, [])


const FilterData = () => {
    if (gender) {
        var searchedResult
        searchedResult = data.filter(
            (e) => e.gender === gender
        );
        console.log(searchedResult)
        console.log(gender)
        setData(searchedResult)
    }
}

if (data) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <select name="Gender" onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
                <button onClick={FilterData}></button>
            </div>

            <ul>
                {data.map((results, idx) => (

                    <li key={idx}>
                        <p>{results.name.first} {results.name.last}</p>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
} else {
    return (
        <div>loading...</div>
    )
}
```